# Kohana - passing variables to a view

Tags: kohana, kohana-3.2

I'm not able to pass a simple variable to the view , can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

I have a controller user :

```
class Controller_User extends Controller_Template_Login {  

     public function action_index()
    {
        $this->template = 'user/info';
        parent::before(); 
        $user = Auth::instance()->get_user();         
        $this->template->content = View::factory('user/info')
            ->bind('user', $user)
            ->bind('message', $message)
            ->bind('errors', $errors);        

        // if a user is not logged in, redirect to login page
        if (!$user)
        {
            Request::current()->redirect('user/login');
        }
    }

}
```

Inside my view (user/info) i get that user is not defined .

what I'm missing ?

**Edit :** Note that this can be fixed by adding the :

```
$user = Auth::instance()->get_user();
```

to the  Controller_Template_Login

```
        $user = Auth::instance()->get_user();
        $this->template->user = $user;
```

What i want to know is why this doesn't work :

```
    $user = Auth::instance()->get_user();         

    $this->template->content = View::factory('user/info')
    ->bind('user', $user)
    ->bind('message', $message)
    ->bind('errors', $errors);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in the first case

```
$this->template->user = $user;
```

you assign `$user` variable to a `user` property of `$this->template`.

And in the second case:

```
$this->template->content = View::factory('user/info')
    ->bind('user', $user)
    ->bind('message', $message)
    ->bind('errors', $errors);
```

you bind `$user` variable to a `user` property of `$this->template->content`.

Comment: So the following code does nothing : $this->template->content = View::factory('user/info') , it only assign the content of the view to template->content but its not used right ?

Comment: @Tarek: this code assigns a view object to the `content` property. If you use `$content` variable in the template - it would be rendered. If not - it doesn't do anything useful